# How profiles are viewed through url?

Tags: php, ajax

Just like facebook when anything is entered at the end of url, is searched and viewed for instance.

www.facebook.com/alex -> profile is viewed that has username alex

similarly

www.facebook.com/abc ->  username with abc, profile is viewed.

How does this work?

Comment: Search for htaccess and url rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multi-stage setup, and a very broad question you've asked.

Primarily it normally works by having a [rewriting filter](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php) (using `.htaccess` or similar functionality), which redirects to something like `profile.php?user=[username]` page. In that page you fetch the username with `$_GET['user']`, and do a DB lookup based upon that.